# insert NA into data read as strings

Tags: r

I have a text file with unequal elements among rows.  Sometimes the second column contains data, sometimes it contains `NA` and sometimes there is nothing recorded at all.  I know that if there are only 4 elements in a row I should insert an `NA` as the element in the second column.  However, I do not know how to do this.  Here is an example data set:

```
abc.def ghi.jkl mno pqr A*
bc.def NA no qr A
c-e.ef non qrr AE
fg.gg no qr E
aa.bb cc.dd ee ff A*
```

Here is the desired result:

```
desired.result <- read.table(text = '
  Name1   Name2  Name3 Name4 Status
abc.def ghi.jkl    mno   pqr     A*
 bc.def      NA     no    qr      A
 c-e.ef      NA    non   qrr     AE
  fg.gg      NA     no    qr      E
  aa.bb   cc.dd     ee    ff     A*
', header = TRUE)
```

I have not gotten far, but I have been able to split the data and input it into a `matrix` with the following code.  Of course, the data are misaligned.

```
setwd('c:/users/mmiller21/simple R programs')

my.data <- readLines('name_data.txt')

matrix(unlist(strsplit(unlist(my.data), " ")), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)

#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]  [,4]      [,5]     
# [1,] "abc.def" "ghi.jkl" "mno" "pqr"     "A*"     
# [2,] "bc.def"  "NA"      "no"  "qr"      "A"      
# [3,] "c-e.ef"  "non"     "qrr" "AE"      "fg.gg"  
# [4,] "no"      "qr"      "E"   "aa.bb"   "cc.dd"  
# [5,] "ee"      "ff"      "A*"  "abc.def" "ghi.jkl"
```

Somehow I should count the number of elements after using `strsplit(unlist(my.data), " ")` then insert `NA` as the second element in every row containing only four elements.  Then input the data into a matrix.  Thank you for any help with this.  I prefer base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `dat` with your filename:

```
dat <- textConnection("abc.def ghi.jkl mno pqr A*
bc.def NA no qr A
c-e.ef non qrr AE
fg.gg no qr E
aa.bb cc.dd ee ff A*")

my.lines  <- readLines(dat)
my.rows   <- strsplit(my.lines, " ")
adjust    <- function(row) {
   if (length(row) == 4) c(head(row, 1), NA, tail(row, 3))
   else row
}
my.fixed  <- lapply(my.rows, adjust)

out <- matrix(unlist(my.fixed), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
out[out == "NA"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dat <- read.table(text="abc.def ghi.jkl mno pqr A*
 bc.def NA no qr A
 c-e.ef non qrr AE
 fg.gg no qr E
 aa.bb cc.dd ee ff A*", fill=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 names(dat) <- c('Name1'  , 'Name2',  'Name3', 'Name4','Status')
 is.na(dat[[5]]) <- dat[[5]]==""   # set blanks in col 5 to NA
 t( apply( dat, 1, function(r) if( is.na( r[5]) ) {r[c(1,5,2:4)]}else {r}))
 #---------
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] "abc.def" "ghi.jkl" "mno" "pqr" "A*"
[2,] "bc.def"  NA        "no"  "qr"  "A" 
[3,] "c-e.ef"  NA        "non" "qrr" "AE"
[4,] "fg.gg"   NA        "no"  "qr"  "E" 
[5,] "aa.bb"   "cc.dd"   "ee"  "ff"  "A*"
```

Comment: That's equivalent to @agstudy's, except his does allow for the last column to contain `NA`s.

Comment: DWin, you changed your name!  (I have not been around this site much in a while.)

Comment: Yeah. I was surprised it didn't change globally across the SE network, so I'm still DWin on CrossValidated. @flodel: I guess that "" is the only length-0 character element. Neither one of our appraoches would move an NA_character_ value in the 5th postion to the second position. I was surprised at what this returned: nchar(NA_character_)

Comment: I had given it a try.... and was surprised at the result. Did you know that `nchar(NA_character_)` would return 2??? It makes agstudy's version behave differently than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use option `fill=TRUE` , then translate the missed rows:

```
dat <- read.table(text='abc.def ghi.jkl mno pqr A*
  bc.def NA no qr A
c-e.ef non qrr AE
fg.gg no qr E
aa.bb cc.dd ee ff A*',fill=TRUE)

t(apply(dat,1,function(x){
  if(nchar(x[5])==0)
    x= c(x[1],NA_character_,x[2:4])
  x
}))

   [,1]      [,2]      [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] "abc.def" "ghi.jkl" "mno" "pqr" "A*"
[2,] "bc.def"  NA        "no"  "qr"  "A" 
[3,] "c-e.ef"  NA        "non" "qrr" "AE"
[4,] "fg.gg"   NA        "no"  "qr"  "E" 
[5,] "aa.bb"   "cc.dd"   "ee"  "ff"  "A*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Readlines, split by space characters, and append NA:

```
txt <- readLines(file)
t(sapply(strsplit(txt, "\\s+"), function(x) if(length(x) < 5) append(x, NA, 1) else x))
#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  
# [1,] "abc.def" "ghi.jkl" "mno" "pqr" "A*"
# [2,] "bc.def"  "NA"      "no"  "qr"  "A" 
# [3,] "c-e.ef"  NA        "non" "qrr" "AE"
# [4,] "fg.gg"   NA        "no"  "qr"  "E" 
# [5,] "aa.bb"   "cc.dd"   "ee"  "ff"  "A*"
```

Full version with data management:

```
file <- tempfile()
cat("abc.def ghi.jkl mno pqr A*
bc.def NA no qr A
c-e.ef non qrr AE
fg.gg no qr E
aa.bb cc.dd ee ff A*", "\n", sep="", file=file)
txt <- readLines(file)
t(sapply(strsplit(txt, "\\s+"), function(x) if(length(x) < 5) append(x, NA, 1) else x))
unlink(file)
```

Note this is similar to @Flodel